# Remove extra space from double quotes in lstlisting environment

Tags: spacing, lstlisting

I have a book in which I'm using lstlisting for pseudocode. In some cases, I have strings, such as here:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
foreach (name in NameCollection)
{
    Print ``Hello, {name}!'' 
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

My problem is that no matter what I do, I end up with a lot of extra space inside the double quotes; they're angled correctly but take up as much space as two characters.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two consecutive backticks ``` `` ``` and two consecutive typewriter apostrophes `''` are TeX ligatures to produce English quotation marks `“` and `”`, respectively. In code listing, you should use a *single* symbol `"`, which is the most common way of introducing a string of text. I also strongly recommend to use a mono spaced font for code listing (they are designed for this purpose!).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
foreach (name in NameCollection)
{
    Print "Hello, {name}!"
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: code listing]

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same results whether I use the two apostrophes or a quote mark. But it does look better with a monospace font.

Comment: @William Is it possible that, when you typed `"`, your TeX editor automatically converted the single symbol into two separate apostrophes? In that case, I suggest using the backspace or Ctrl+Z to get the single `"` back.

Comment: Huh, you're right - it did!